# Два условия в JOIN запросе

Tags: sql, join

Есть таблицы:

```
product
id 
1

product_property
id 
1
2

product_has_property
id property_id product_id
1 1 1
2 2 1
```

Такой запрос срабатывает нормально:

```
SELECT "product".* FROM "product" 
LEFT JOIN "product_has_property" "hp" ON "product"."id" = "hp"."product_id"
WHERE ("hp"."property_id"='1')
```

Выводится продукт со свойством 1.

Но такой запрос не срабатывает, не выводит ничего:

```
SELECT "product".* FROM "product" 
LEFT JOIN "product_has_property" "hp" ON "product"."id" = "hp"."product_id"
WHERE ("hp"."property_id"='1') AND ("hp"."property_id"='2')
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём проблема, по логике вроде норм? И как правильно построить запрос, чтобы выводить продукт по двум свойствам?

Comment: а вы почитайте что такое логическое `И` (`AND`) и `ИЛИ` (`OR`) и все сразу ясно станет. А еще можете про синтаксис `IN ....` почитать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в условии пишите:

```
WHERE ("hp"."property_id"='1') AND ("hp"."property_id"='2')
```

т.е. у Вас`"hp"."property_id"` должно быть равно и `1` и `2` одновременно. Естественно, что такого не получится.

Вам нужно `OR`:

```
WHERE ("hp"."property_id"='1') OR ("hp"."property_id"='2')
```

Или же `IN`:

```
WHERE "hp"."property_id" IN ('1', '2')
```

Comment: Спасибо, логика не верна )